# Font loaded via package in XeTeX behaves differently on polyglossia or babel

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, babel, polyglossia

First of all, I know I should not use [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) in XeTeX, but this weird problem is bugging me.

Here is the MWE I created on Overleaf:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\iftrue
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
\else
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
\fi

\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

\begin{document}
\section*{This is a section title}
And this is a body text.
\end{document}
```

Since I gave the option `default` to [`sourcesanspro`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sourcesanspro), I expected it to be applied all across the document. However, this is what I get:
[image: Polyglossia.png]
So, the font has only been applied to the section title, not to the body text.

Now, let's deactivate [`polyglossia`](http://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) and activate [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) by changing line 5 from `\iftrue` to `\iffalse`. Then I get:
[image: Babel]
It can be seen that the font has been applied to both.

At first, I thought this would be a problem of [`sourcesanspro`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sourcesanspro), but now I don't even know what's the cause. I haven't checked if this is Overleaf-specific problem; so FYI, here're the links to the above MWE on Overleaf when applied [polyglossia](https://www.overleaf.com/read/srwtqybyvkyq) or [babel](https://www.overleaf.com/read/jxphqrvjzbpj).

Any lead on this problem, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sourcesanspro` package resets `\familydefault,` but not `\rmdefault`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\iftrue 
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
\else
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
\fi

\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\edef\rmdefault{\sfdefault} % this is missing in sourcesanspro

\begin{document}
\section*{This is a section title}
And this is a body text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thank you! But I am still curious why this depends on which multilingual package I load...

Comment: @ArdieHyunHwang Apparently `polyglossia` relies on `\rmdefault`